# Debian - how to dump virtual hosts

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, virtualhost

With Apache 2 running on windows or other Linux distros (eg Centos) you can show a list of virtual hosts by typing **httpd -S** at the command line. You get a nice listing of virtual hosts and where they are defined. Debian doesn't seem to support this with the equivalent apache2 -S command, spitting out this error:

```
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

At first I thought there was a problem with apache env vars but apparently everything works OK. However, I still would like to be able to see a list of all my vhosts. Any ideas how I can do this easily?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Debian/Ubuntu use the following:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Comment: This apprears to work exactly how I need, thanks very much.

Comment: apachectl -S works for centOS

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the username and group environment variables defined.
Try `APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data apache2 -S`

(replace www-data with the username/group apache is running of)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure that the correct information has been set in /etc/apache2/envvars - this file is read by the apache2 command to know which user should be running the Apache httpd.

See more information in [apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804436) at the Ubuntu forums.

Comment: I've checked envvars - it's fine. Like I said there are no problems with envvars - the problem is that this build of apache on debian clearly isn't able to report vhosts using the apache2 -S command like it always has been able to in the past. Now I'm looking for an alternative way to dump virtual hosts.

Comment: Actually, that file *isn't* read by `apache2`, it's read by the `apache2ctl` and init scripts.  You'll need to source it yourself if you are running the server binary by hand (execute `. /etc/apache2/envvars` in the same shell first)

Comment: @DerfK You're right. It's read by /etc/init.d/apache2 - not the binary itself. I got confused.